# Selective indexing in bulbflow without using Models

Tags: python, neo4j, bulbs

I'm using bulbflow (python) with Neo4j and I'm trying to add an index *only* on a subset of my keys (for now, simply keys named 'name' for optional index-based lookup).

I don't love the bulbflow Models (too restrictive) and I couldn't figure out how to do selective indexing without changing code since the 'autoindex' is a global setting -- I don't see how to configure it based on the key.

Has anyone done something like this?

-Andrew

Comment: Have you taken a look at the index docs? http://bulbflow.com/api/bulbs/neo4jserver/indices/#vertex-index-proxy

Comment: Thanks LC,I've been working on those but it's at a very low level of the API.  Basically, I want selective auto-indexing on only certain properties.  With this low-level API, it looks like I'd have to do my regular data writes, and then create a Neo4jClient object to call the methods 'create_indexed_vertex' and 'update_indexed_vertex' when anything gets modified.  I could go to the VertexIndexProxy class but that doesn't seem necessary unless I'm missing something.  Either way, a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable Bulbs auto-indexing by setting `g.config.autoindex` to `False`.

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/config.py#L62

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
>>> g.config.autoindex = False
>>> g.vertices.create(name="James")
```

In the example above, this will cause the `name` property not to be indexed automatically.

Setting `autoindex` to `False` will switch to using the low-level client's `create_vertex()` method instead of the `create_indexed_vertex()` method:

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py#L422

The `create_indexed_vertex()` method has a `keys` arg, which you can use for selective indexing:

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py#L424

This is the low-level `client` method used by Bulbs models. You generally don't need to explicitly call the low-level client methods, but if you do, you can selectively index properties by including the property name in the keys arg.

To selectively index properties in a Model, simply override `get_index_keys()` in your Model definition:

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/model.py#L383

By default, Bulbs models index all properties. If no keys are provided, then all properties are indexed (like in TinkerPop/Blueprints).

See the Model _create() and get_bundle() methods:

- `_create()` https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/model.py#L583
- `get_bundle()` https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/model.py#L363
- `get_index_keys()` https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/model.py#L383

To enable selective indexing for generic vertices and edges, I updated the Bulbs generic vertex/edge methods to include a `_keys` arg where you can supply a list of property names (keys) to index.

See  https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/commit/4fe39d5a76675020286ec9aeaa8e71d58e3a432a

Now, to selectively index properties on generic vertices/edges, you can supply a list of property names to index:

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
>>> g.config.autoindex = False
>>> james = g.vertices.create(name="James", city="Dallas", _keys=["name"])
>>> julie = g.vertices.create(name="Julie", city="Dallas", _keys=["name"])
>>> g.edges.create(james, "knows", julie, timestamp=12345, someprop="somevalue", _keys=["someprop"])
```

In the example above, the `name` property will be indexed for each vertex, and `someprop` will be indexed for the edge. Note that `city` and `timestamp` will not be indexed because those property names were not explicitly included in the list of index keys.

If `g.config.autoindex` is `True` and `_keys` is `None` (the default), all properties will be indexed (just like before).

If `g.config.autoindex` is `False` and `_keys` is `None`, no properties will be indexed.

If `_keys` is explicitly set to a list of property names, only those properties will be indexed, regardless if `g.config.autoindex` is `True` or `False`.

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py#L422

**NOTE**: How auto-indexing works differs somewhat if you're using Neo4j Server, Rexster, or Titan Server, and the indexing architecture for all the graph-database servers has been in a state of flux for the past few months. It appears that all are moving from a manual-indexing system to auto-indexing.

For graph-database servers that did not have auto-indexing capability until recently (e.g. Neo4j Server), Bulbs enabled auto-indexing via custom Gremlin scripts that used the database's low-level manual indexing methods:

- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py#L1008
- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/gremlin.groovy#L11

However, manual indexing has been deprecated among Neo4j Server, TinkerPop/Rexster, and Titan Server so Bulbs 0.4 indexing architecture will change accordingly. Selective indexing will still be possible by declaring your index keys upfront, like you would in an SQL `create table` statement.

**BTW**: What about did you find restrictive about Models? Bulbs Models (actually the entire library) is designed to be flexible so you can modify it to whatever you need.

See the Lightbulb example for how to customize Bulbs Models: [Is there a equivalent to commit in bulbs framework for neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759606/is-there-a-equivalent-to-commit-in-bulbs-framework-for-neo4j/16764036#16764036)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Regarding Bulbs Models being 'restrictive' -- that is certainly the wrong word.  Our data model is relatively simple and fluid (no data on edges, only two type of edge labels, cycle-less tree connectivity rather than a general graph, and oft-changing property key-vals only on the vertices) so I didn't need the _slight_ overhead of Models.