# How to make a selective fulltext index for neo4j in bulbs framework for Python?

Tags: python, indexing, neo4j, full-text-indexing, bulbs

James Thronton provides an excellent example of how to configure bulbs to use a fulltext index as default index for all neo4j fileds here: https://gist.github.com/espeed/3025438

However, is there a way of manually managing fulltext indexes so that they only cover some properties on some node types? If yes, how it is done?

Comment: So far it seems that adding `Graph.build_proxy(foo, FulltextIndex)` is able to build a fulltext index for a specific node type. Is it possible to do the same thing for a specific property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer on how to do selective indexing in Bulbs without models...

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20046763/161085

And if you don't want to use the `FulltextIndex` as the default index (presumably for performance reasons), you can manually `put` the values to be indexed:

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph, FulltextIndex
>>> from bulbs.element import Vertex
>>> index_name="fulltext_vertex"
>>> g = Graph()
>>> g.vertices.fulltext = g.factory.get_index(Vertex, FulltextIndex, index_name) 
>>> james = g.vertices.create(name="James Thornton", city="Dallas")
>>> g.vertices.fulltext.put(james.eid, name=james.name)
>>> vertices = g.vertices.fulltext.query(name="James")
>>> vertices.next()
```

See...

- Bulbs Docs http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/neo4jserver/indices/#fulltext-index
- Index https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/index.py#L228
- Fulltext https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/index.py#L483

And to automate the fulltext indexing behavior without making the fulltext index the default index, use a Bulbs `Model` and create a custom `Graph` object.

See my answer on how to customize Bulbs models...

- [Is there a equivalent to commit in bulbs framework for neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759606/is-there-a-equivalent-to-commit-in-bulbs-framework-for-neo4j/16764036#16764036)

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit confused on the parameters to supply to the  FulltextIndex init method and couldn't find it anywhere.