# Python - Bulbs - Models - Class initialization

Tags: python, bulbs

I'm learning how to use Bulbs models, I have questions on Node classes initialization.

From the documentation:

```
from bulbs.model import Node, Relationship
from bulbs.property import String, Integer, DateTime
from bulbs.utils import current_datetime

class Person(Node):

    element_type = "person"

    name = String(nullable=False)
    age = Integer()
```

How can I perform data manipulation before saving the data in the node?

Can I perform something like

```
class Person(Node):

    element_type = "person"

    name = String(nullable=False)
    if name == "Bar":
        name = "Foo"
```

Or I have to override the Node init?

```
class Person(Node):

    element_type = "person"

    name = String(nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name):
        if name == "Bar":
            self.name = "Foo"
```

Comment: Have you tried either of them? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Override the model's `_create()` method.

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/model.py#L565

Also see 'Customizing Bulbs Models Example":

[Is there a equivalent to commit in bulbs framework for neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759606/is-there-a-equivalent-to-commit-in-bulbs-framework-for-neo4j/16764036#16764036)